# Getting Proper JSON response in PHP

Tags: php, angularjs, json, database

I am pretty new to PHP, I have referred some examples and made a code for getting data from database. but if the database is not found I am getting a text response , Can anyone suggest how to get a proper JSON response back if no database found or misconfigured

This is my $http.get method

```
 $http.get('client/php/popData.php')
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.blogs = data;
        })
        .error(function(err) {
            $log.error(err);
        })
```

popdata.php for getting data from database

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

include('config.php');

$db = new DB();

$data = $db->qryFire();

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

This is my config.php

```
<?php
define("__HOST__", "localhost");
define("__USER__", "username");
define("__PASS__", "password");
define("__BASE__", "databasename");

class DB {
    private $con = false;
    private $data = array();

    public function __construct() {
        $this->con = new mysqli(__HOST__, __USER__, __PASS__, __BASE__);

        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            die("DB connection failed:" . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
    }

    public function qryPop() {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `base` ORDER BY `id` DESC";
        $qry = $this->con->query($sql);
        if($qry->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $qry->fetch_object()) {
                $this->data[] = $row;
            }
        } else {
            $this->data[] = null;
        }
        $this->con->close();
    }

    public function qryFire($sql=null) {
        if($sql == null) {
            $this->qryPop();
        } else {
            $this->con->query($sql);
            $this->qryPop();    
        }
        // $this->con->close();
        return $this->data;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Send a 500 status code, then your error will get caught in your jquery callback :)

Comment: should consider returning different http status codes like 404 not found or 500 for db connection problems and set up your error handling to check status and react accordingly. Note that `success` and `error` are deprecated in $http per docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php):

Change your class `DB` like this:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->con = new mysqli(__HOST__, __USER__, __PASS__, __BASE__);

    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        throw new Exception("DB connection failed:" . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
}
```

Then change your popdata.php like

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));


include('config.php');

try {
    $db = new DB();
    $data = $db->qryFire();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
    exit();
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

This way you will get error response in JSON for any Exception thrown while constructing the `DB` class and while executing `DB::qryFire`

if you want to catch your warnings you can try modifying your `DB` class like the below:

```
public function __construct() {
    ob_start();
    $this->con = new mysqli(__HOST__, __USER__, __PASS__, __BASE__);
    $warning = ob_clean();

    if ($warning) {
        throw new Exception($warning);
    }

    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        throw new Exception("DB connection failed:" . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
}
```

You can also turn off your warnings and notices by adding

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
```

on the top of your file

Comment: whatever i do ..I get these line before that..                                                              <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
 in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\client\php\config.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br />

Comment: @SibiRaj will you consider this as the correct answer in that case?or  is there anything else I can do for you ?

Answer (score 0):

replace the line `die("DB connection failed:" . mysqli_connect_error());` in DB class __construct function with

```
die( json_encode( array('status' => 'error') ) );
```

when ever the app will fail to connect to the data base it will give

```
{"status": "error"}
```

*i did not checked this. but i hope it will work*

btw it's my 1st answer on stackoverflow. i'm sorry for my mistakes. correct them

Comment: I Checked this this works fine but the whole response is as follows    ==>  <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
 in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\client\php\config.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br />

Comment: whatever i do ..I get these line before that..                                                              <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
 in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\client\php\config.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br />